# Existence of a special linear subspace (of the dual of a subspace)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $Z \subset  X^*$ a separable linear subspace. Then there is a separable linear subspace $Y \subset X$ such that $Z$ is isometrically isomorphic to a linear subspace of $Y^*$.

$X^*$ denotes the continuous(?) dual space, that is $X^*=\{ f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{K} : f\ linear\ and\ continuous\}$.

This result rather astonishes me. I cannot explain myself why it holds, even less figure out a proof.

Can someone perhaps drop me a hint on what to focus on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a separable subspace $Y$ of $X$ on which $Z$ acts isometrically, i.e. each $z \in Z$ attains its norm on $Y$. Then by Hanh-Banach, $Y^*$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $X^*$ by the kernel of the restriction map (i.e. the annihilators of $Y$). Since no $z \in Z$ annihilates $Y$, $Z$ embeds into $Y^*$, and does so isometrically.

To construct $Y$, take a dense sequence $\{ z_n \}$ in $Z$. For each $z_n$, find a unit vector $x_n$ such that $|z_n(x_n)| = ||z_n||$. Let $Y$ be the (closed, if you'd like) subspace generated by $\{ x_n\}$.